# Script to append the file

Tags: powershell

This is the end of my script. I am looking to make this code append the data every time it's run. Currently it overwrites the file. I can paste the whole script if needed.

```
Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"
#$PathArray | ForEach-Object {$_}
$PathArray | % {$_} | Out-File "C:\SearchString\Output.txt"
```

Comment: `Get-Help Out-File` will show you an `-Append` parameter

Comment: `Get-Content`, `Set-Content`, and .. `Add-Content`.

Answer (score 2):

`Out-File` has an `-Append` parameter. Simply modify your code to have it tagged on at the end.

Though, your `ForEach-Object` statement (the `%` symbol) is pretty useless in the pipeline and isn't needed. This is because you are only using the `ForEach` loop to output the object without any modification. This is exactly what the pipeline does by default, which is pass each object along to the next command.

> For more information on the pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6
>
> If `Update-Help` has been run locally, one can use `Get-Help about_pipelines` to see information too.

Instead of this:

```
$PathArray | % {$_} | Out-File "C:\SearchString\Output.txt" -Append
```

You could do this:

```
$PathArray | Out-File "C:\SearchString\Output.txt" -Append
```

**[Recommended]** You can also eliminate the need for the pipeline all together, as using a pipeline is less efficient if it can be done without it. Doing everything one can possibly do without the pipeline, or to the left of each pipe in the pipeline, is to **"filter left"** (see the following article for more about why one should *filter left, format right*: [Filtering Command Output in PowerShell](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/01/16/filtering-command-output-in-powershell.aspx)):

```
Out-File -InputObject $PathArray -FilePath "C:\SearchString\Output.txt" -Append
```

The easiest way to troubleshoot is to checkout help documentation. Use `Get-Help` to checkup whatever you need: parameter sets, available parameters, examples, etc. Make sure to run `Update-Help` in order to have detailed documentation available locally. To checkout everything:

```
Update-Help    
Get-Help Out-File -Full
```

> For more information on help documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help?view=powershell-6

*Note: Another answer to this question can be found here, where it uses the `>` and `>>` symbols: [powershell append to output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562103/powershell-append-to-output)*